# Add library to aws lambda. ("errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'XXXXXl'")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, package

I have a working AWS lambda, when I test it with an API Gateway, it compile.

Then I add `import openpyxl` and it crash, understandable but now.

**Problem:** How to add library to AWS lambda ?

.

**Possible solution:**

On AWS lambda interface -> Actions -> load zip

Problem: What do I put on the .zip ?

- [.whl or .tar.gz from openpyxl official website ?](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#files) (I tried but it didn't work).
- corresponding library folder on `site-packages` ? (dependencies problems ? I didn't even found the `openpyxl` folder.

I found everything really easy till this moment where the documentation and the "Hello World tutorial" seems to disappear. But this is so important that I can't image that to be difficult, no ?

Comment: AWS docs explain this quite well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies

Comment: Thanks, that's right, AWS explain well but it's hard to find where it's well explained ! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question: this link solve everything (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies)